# Efficiency in filling an array

Tags: c#

I am coding an application that asks a user to enter a word, and then the program checks if there are any words contained within the larger word that are in the dictionary. For example, if the user entered "starburst", the system would output "star" and "burst".

I am creating my own dictionary of words within the program. So far I have an array, and I simply go one by one and add different words to the dictionary. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

code posted below:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a word");
    string word = Console.ReadLine();
    string word2 = word;
    string [] dictionary = new string[300];
    dictionary[0] = "apple";
    dictionary[1] = "adversary";
    dictionary[2] = "apply";
    dictionary[3] = "be";
    dictionary[4] = "bear";
    dictionary[5] = "Bare";
    dictionary[6] = "car";
    dictionary[7] = "care";
    dictionary[8] = "cat";
    dictionary[9] = "carreer";
    dictionary[10] = "day";
    dictionary[11] = "dare";
    dictionary[12] = "date";
    dictionary[13] = "do";
    dictionary[14] = "double";
    dictionary[15] = "ex";
    dictionary[16] = "extra";
    dictionary[17] = "can";
    dictionary[18] = "dog";
    dictionary[19] = "dont";

    for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int n = word2.Length; n < dictionary.Length; n++)
        {
            if (word == dictionary[n] && word != word2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(word);
            }
            if(word2 == dictionary[n] && word != word2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(word2);
            }
            word.Substring(1, word.Length - 1);
            word2.Substring(0, word2.Length - 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  No one can tell you if your code is efficient if you dont post it.

Comment: There is no easy way to make this fast. But you could use a `HashSet<string>` or a sorted list as your dictionary and that would speed your look ups.

Comment: Pertaining to the program just closing, Console applications will do this when running from Visual Studio if they aren't waiting on user input. Adding a call to `Console.ReadLine()` or `Console.ReadKey()` at the end of your Main method will suffice to remedy this.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

I assume you mean not having to manually change the array initialization code and recompile the application when you want to add a word to the dictionary.

You could do this by putting your word list in a file, and reading it with `string [] dictionary = File.ReadAllLines("dictionary.txt")`.